# How to do a distinct count of one field, grouped by another in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

If I wanted to create a dataframe, which is equivalent to this SQL in PANDAS how would I do it?

```
SELECT COUNTRY, COUNT(DISTINCT PRODUCT) AS UNIQUE_PRODUCTS 
FROM SALES
GROUP BY COUNTY
```

Answer (score 3):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Country': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
    'Product': ['X', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'Y', 'Z']    
})

df.groupby('Country').Product.nunique()
>>>
Country
A    1
B    3
C    2
Name: Product, dtype: int64
```

Comment: to match OP requirement :) +1 `df.groupby('Country',as_index=False).agg(unique_products=('Product','nunique'))`

Comment: your code doesnt work for me. what is your pandas version?

Comment: named aggregations were added in a later version of pandas i think`0.24`?

Comment: you are right. maybe after 25? mine is '0.24.2'. btw i should switch to 1.2.x :)